# Android Studio and Gradle: content is not allowed in prolog when having a .jar in /libs folder

Tags: java, android-studio, build, gradle, libraries

I'm working on an Android Studio project that is in github and has both Mac and Windows computers modifying the project. I attempted to create a gitignore to avoid committing OS-specific files to the project, but still see this error after I pull changes committed on a Windows Machine: **Content is not allowed in prolog**

From my understanding, Gradle suddenly does not like me having a .jar within /res/libs folder. Last time I fixed this error by removing and relinking the .jar, but **is there an easier way to fix "content not allowed in prolog" error?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after trying to add a .jar file in my Android Studio project. Nothing would work until i deleted every jar in my libs folder and re-entered them. Hope this helps some unlucky visitor!